# Get list of functions used in a view

Tags: postgresql, view, functions, dependencies

Say I have a Function like this:

```
create function house_analysis(ingeo geometry)
  returns table(count_all numeric, count_important numeric) as
$$
  select count(*), count(*) filter (where h.import_flag)
  from house_table h where st_intersects(ingeo, h.geom)
$$ language sql stable;
```

And I define a View like this:

```
create or replace view postzone_analysis as (
  select p.zipcode, ha.count_all, ha.count_important
  from postzone_table p, house_analysis(p.geom) ha
);
```

The question is:

How can I query the system catalogs (`pg_catalog.*`) with my view (`postzone_analysis` or its `oid`) get a list of the functions used within it? Their `pg_proc.oid` values are fine.

I know the database keeps track, since I cannot drop the function, but I can't find the entries in `pg_depend`.

DB is PostgreSQL 9.5.

(The real-life case is a lot more complex - it's scoped down to be lowest viable example. The view calls like 6 analysis functions, which combines the data from difference sources, and there are multiple views that are based on different area classes.)

Comment: maybe this can help: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pg_depend_display

Comment: And by functions you mean user-defined functions, or PL/pqSQL functions or all functions?

Comment: Well, the most important part are user-defined functions (SQL or PL/pgSQL), but it's possible get get all function usages and filter them afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views are implemented as table plus ***rewrite rule*** in Postgres. Details in the manual, chapter [***Views and the Rule System***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-views.html).

The tricky part: not the view itself depends on involved functions, only the rewrite rule does. So this query should be your solution:

```
SELECT r.ev_class::regclass AS view, d.refobjid::regprocedure AS function
FROM   pg_rewrite r
JOIN   pg_depend  d ON d.objid = r.oid 
                   AND d.refclassid = 'pg_proc'::regclass  -- only functions
WHERE  r.ev_class = 'v123'::regclass;  -- name of view here (optionally schema-qualified)
```

Returns all user-defined functions (excluding built-in functions).

The query assumes you did not define any additional rules for the view. Else filter the one with `rulename = '_RETURN'`, which is the default name for the rewrite rules of a view.

The cast to [`regprocedure`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) (not just `regproc`) returns the function with argument types, uniquely identifying it. The name is schema-qualified automatically if the current `search_path` would not resolve differently otherwise.