# Get base table from materialized view in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I use materialized view in postgresql. when retrieving the list of materialized view (select * from pg_matviews), in the "definition" column, there is a query building the materialized view. how do i retrieve the list of base tables from "definition"?

example query materialized view :

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW rental_by_category
AS
SELECT c.name AS category,
    sum(p.amount) AS total_sales
   FROM (((((payment p
     JOIN rental r ON ((p.rental_id = r.rental_id)))
     JOIN inventory i ON ((r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id)))
     JOIN film f ON ((i.film_id = f.film_id)))
     JOIN film_category fc ON ((f.film_id = fc.film_id)))
     JOIN category c ON ((fc.category_id = c.category_id)))
  GROUP BY c.name
  ORDER BY sum(p.amount) DESC
WITH NO DATA;
```

i want to get list of materialized view like this:

> rental_by_category
>
> ```
> base table
> payment
> rental
> inventory
> film
> film_category
> category
> ```

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/158812/3684

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this should do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  pg_class.oid::regclass
FROM pg_rewrite
JOIN pg_depend ON
  pg_depend.classid = 'pg_rewrite'::regclass AND
  pg_depend.objid = pg_rewrite.oid AND
  pg_depend.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass AND
  pg_depend.refobjid <> pg_rewrite.ev_class
JOIN pg_class ON
  pg_class.oid = pg_depend.refobjid AND
  pg_class.relkind IN ('r','f','p','v','m')
WHERE
  pg_rewrite.ev_class = 'rental_by_category'::regclass
```

This should show any tables or views which are *directly* referenced by the view. If your view references other views, and you want to drill down to the base tables, you would need to apply this logic recursively (probably with a `RECURSIVE` [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)).

`pg_class.relkind IN ('r','f','p','v','m')` covers all of the table and view types as of Postgres 11, but the list may change in future releases. The possible values are covered in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html).

Many different kinds of dependencies are stored in [`pg_depend`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-depend.html), and not all of them are relevant to your question. For example, the view's `pg_rewrite` entry has a dependency on its own `pg_class` entry; the `pg_depend.refobjid <> pg_rewrite.ev_class` constraint is there to filter this out. I may well have overlooked something else which ought to be excluded, so proceed with caution.